# virtual box centos7 got ssh_exchange_identification: read: Connection reset by peer

Tags: windows, ssh, linux-mint

guys. i had a problem with ssh to another virtual machine. Here is my environment:
i have two physical machines , one is linux mint and the other is window8
i have a virtual box installed on win8 besides launched centos7. i had sshd service setted up in centos7 and port redirecting from win8 2222 to centos 22. 
when i typed `ssh -p 2222 user@win8's address` i got this:

```
ssh_exchange_identification: read: Connection reset by peer
```

however when i establish a connection using XManager with address 127.0.0.1 on port 2222, it connected!